# simple question about number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a name to the theorem that says for integers $a,b,c$ where $a$ is prime, 
if $a\mid bc$ and $(a,b)=1$ then $a\mid c$

Comment: not deep enough to be called a theorem I guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called Euclid's lemma, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma

Comment: What I've always thought Euclid's lemma says is a slightly weaker statement: if $a$ is prime and $a\mid bc$ then $a\mid b$ or $a\mid c$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: So did I. Now according to the Wikipedia article, this more general fact is also called Euclid's lemma. I guess we should just go to the source http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVII/propVII30.html

Comment: In several countries this theorem is called Gauss theorem or lemma